# Connecting line with polygon edge using ArcGIS Topology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I have to connect many of these points with the edges of polygons.

I am using Topology, but the "must not have Dangles" allow to connect two lines together, not a polygon edge and a line.

Can someone help me?

[image: description]

Comment: Do you have Advanced License? If so, you can convert the polygons to lines, add them to the other lines layer (but with an attribute to tell them apart) and run the topology again for the new layer

Comment: Yes, I have advanced licence but I need to keep polygons, I cannot trasnform in lines...

Comment: You don't delete the polygons, you just additionally convert them to lines, so that they can participate in the topology and adjust the other lines so that there are no dangles. Then, you can delete the lines that were created from the polygons